# List of possible events for use in Webhooks method

Tags: callfire

I would like to create a webhook using callfire's api on outbound calls when the "transfer digit" is pressed by the user.

The webhooks method is found here:
https://developers.callfire.com/docs.html#createWebhook

Is shows an example in the post payload like this:

`curl -u username:password -H 
"Content-Type:application/json" -X POST"
localhost:8080/callfire-api-v2/v2/webhooks" 
-d '{"name":"API hook", "resource":"textCampaign", "events":["start", "stop"], "callback":"http://cool.site.xyz/webhook"}'`

This example shows the events "start" and "stop" for a "textCampaign" .  This is the only list of events I can find in the documentation.

I was hoping to find a list of events for each resource.

I would like to use a webhook to get call results for voice calls without having to poll for them.

It might look like this assuming these events and resources existed:

`-d '{"name":"API hook", "resource":"voiceCampaign", "events":["finalCallResult"], "callback":"blah"}'`

Is there a way that one infers the resources and specifically, the events that are available for webhooks?

Answer (score 0):

currently API v2 for webhooks is in beta and doesn't have some statuses, events and other things.

I would recommend to use subscriptions in API v1.1 https://www.callfire.com/api-documentation/rest/version/1.1#!/subscription

Comment: I ended up mainly using the 1.1 version still.  I find it odd that they have so much partial functionality documented in the 2.0 version that isn't really working. I did end up in their chat room several times and they were very helpful.